# Datagrip DB connection error - Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost

Tags: docker, docker-compose, datagrip

I saw this issue when I started to work on the project, but didn't try to find a solution before. For now, I think, this is a real issue and try to know its reason, but couldn't find possible answers.

Reproducing the issue

- `Docker` and `MySQL` were integrated for backend development(Elixir based).
- `Docker-compose up` to build container and use DB by seeding large testing data - there is no problem for using dockerized backend and DB at this point.
- Restart PC. `Docker-compose up` to use an existing container.

Now, an exception error shows in Datagrip:

```
java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
```

So, I had to `Docker-compose stop`, `Docker-compose down` to remove container and after that, run `Docker-compose up` to use DB properly.

Not sure why it is impossible to use an existing container after restarting PC.

Please provide any solution as I am having a difficulty to seed large testing data everytime I restart PC.

Comment: Make sure the container is started properly after restart. Since `docker-compose up` is not guarantee that MySQL is started and container is healthy. Don't you have any errors in container?

Comment: I don't have any errors for the container as they are running well.

Comment: Did you try to use `Disconnect`(red square button) for your data source instead of restarting containers?

Comment: Yes, I tried to use Disconnect and restarted containers. The only available way was to remove all containers and start again. I think, this case is very special as I haven't had this issue before and project is large.

Comment: Did you try to connect to MySQL container using `mysql` cli?

Comment: I didn't try. For now, I cannot see that case anymore. Not sure if it is a temporary status.